# sql query in GEOquery library

Tags: r

I'm trying to download from GEO db all the entries concerning experiments involving "breast cancer cell lines time series gene expression profiles". I'm using the GEOquery R package and the query I'm submitting is the following:

```
> sql <- paste("SELECT DISTINCT gse.title,gse.gse", "FROM", 
               " gsm JOIN gse_gsm ON gsm.gsm=gse_gsm.gsm", 
               " JOIN gse ON gse_gsm.gse=gse.gse", 
               " JOIN gse_gpl ON gse_gpl.gse=gse.gse", 
               " JOIN gpl ON gse_gpl.gpl=gpl.gpl", "WHERE", 
               " gsm.molecule_ch1 like '%total RNA%' AND", 
               " gse.title LIKE '%breast cancer cell lines time series gene expression profiles%' AND",  
               " gpl.organism LIKE '%Homo sapiens%'",  sep = " ")

>rs <- dbGetQuery(con, sql)
```

Now, the output is 1 dataset. It seems to be too few and so wrong because we certainly know that a lot of time series experiments have been performed on  breast cancer cell lines. I suppose, I'm making a mistake in my sql query probabily in the "title". Can anyone help me?

Comment: Hum, I think this question would harness more energy at the biostar stackexchange. It has little to do with R, and a lot to do with specific database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query looks for the substring
`breast cancer cell lines time series gene expression profiles`:
the words have to appear exactly in this order, with nothing inbetween.
You can try to split it, for instance (you may need to split it further):

```
    gse.title LIKE '%breast cancer cell lines%'
AND gse.title LIKE '%time series%'
AND gse.title LIKE '%gene expression profiles%'
```

With some databases, `LIKE` is case-sensitive:
in this case, `ILIKE` may be preferable.